# Ruby: How to count the number of spaces at the beginning and end of a string?

Tags: ruby, string, count, space

To count the number of spaces at the beginning and end of string `s` I do:

```
s.index(/[^ ]/)              # Number of spaces at the beginning of s
s.reverse.index(/[^ ]/)      # Number of spaces at the end of s
```

This approach requires the edge case when `s` contains spaces only to be handled separately.

Is there a better (more elegant / efficient) method to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

another version, this must be the shortest possible

```
s[/\A */].size
s[/ *\z/].size
```

Comment: Better `*` instead of `+` for cases like " aa" or empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it at once:

```
_, spaces_at_beginning, spaces_at_end = /^( *).*?( *)$/.match(s).to_a.map(&:length)
```

Definitely not more elegant though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is more efficient, but this works as well.

```
s.count(' ') - s.lstrip.count(' ')
s.count(' ') - s.rstrip.count(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also easy to do:

```
beginning =  s.length - s.lstrip.length
ending = s.length - s.rstrip.length
```

Comment: This approach won't work if `s` contains other white spaces, e.g. `s = "\tx"`

Comment: The `\t` would count as a single space. However, probably I've not understood what you meant; how would you want to treat the tab case?

Comment: `\t` should be treated as any other character. The question is about counting spaces.

Comment: I'm sorry then, i didn't understand properly your question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
s.split(s.strip).first.size
s.split(s.strip).last.size
```

you could also do

```
beginning_spaces_length , ending_spaces_length = s.split(s.strip).map(&:size)
```